# Comparing two images without fully downloading?

Tags: browser, images, png

I want to download a copy of a big image file(+20MB) whenever it changes. But without downloading it every X seconds and comparing it with the old version i have, how would i know the image has changed or not? Otherwise it would be very bandwidth consuming and slow.

Is there a way to determine size of the picture before downloading it fully? So, when the size has changed that means image has changed too.

Can we compare two images without downloading them(or just by downloading  first few kilobytes)? In other words, does images contain a size information or hash value? Or something like that.

Comment: Do you have any control over the server?

Comment: No i don't. I'm just a visitor.

Comment: You should contact the owner of the server for some assistance perhaps you can work something out for a better solution. You should do this anyways, so you don't waste their bandwidth, serving the same content over and over.

Comment: comparing file sizes is not an accurate way of determining if the image data has changed.  An image may have metadata that has changed, but the image itself has not.

Comment: Did any answer help you? Do you want to set one as solution?

Answer (score 1):

Wget allows you to download only, when the server side file is newer:

```
       When running Wget with -N, with or without -r or -p, the decision
       as to whether or not to download a newer copy of a file depends on
       the local and remote timestamp and size of the file.  -nc may not
       be specified at the same time as -N.
```

Comment: Did this help you? Please mark it as solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1:** The file server may allow directory access.  Try accessing and then parsing the parent directory output.  Example: https://www.kernel.org/pub/site/

**Approach 2:** In code, retrieve the "content-length" header field to get the file size which *may* be an indicator that the file has changed.  Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983073/how-to-know-the-size-of-a-file-before-downloading-it/12271781#12271781

**Approach 3:** Ask the server administrator to provide a checksum which you can download, a notification that a new file is available, or some other form of shell / directory access.

Comment: What about Etags?